# How to structure a url to filter if a query string parameter exists in Django

Tags: django, api, url, filter, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter my 'Posts' model by a parameter passed into a query string in the url. If this parameter is not given, I want the url to just return all posts.

To my (obviously incorrect) understanding, the following is how it should work:

urls.py:

```
path('feed?category=<str:category>', views.Posts.as_view())
```

views.py:

```
def Posts(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        if self.kwargs['category']:
            queryset = Post.objects.filter(category_name = self.kwargs['category'])
        else:
            queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

With the above code, I would expect that by requesting a url `.../feed`, the view would set the queryset to all posts, however if I entered a url `.../feed?category=x` it would only return posts of this category.

Currently, the program does not function as such. How would I accomplish this functionality?

Thanks, Grae

Comment: `path` only checks the *path* of the URL, the part after the `?` is *not* the path, that is the *query string*, so you can not filter with that in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` only checks the *path* of the URL, the part after the `?` is *not* the path, that is the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), so you can not filter with that in the path. The query string is stored in [**`request.GET`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) a dictionary-like object.

You thus define the path as:

```
path('feed/', views.PostView.as_view())
```

and in the view, you can filter with:

```
def PostView(APIView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'category' in self.request.GET:
            return queryset.filter(category_name=self.request.GET['category'])
        return queryset
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `PostView`, instead of <s>`Posts`</s>.

Comment: If the query string is a dictionary item then can I not access the 'category' variable using self.kwargs['category']?

Comment: Would it work to instead use: if 'category' in self.request.kwargs ?

Comment: @GraeCumming: no, a `request` object has *no* `.kwargs`, only the view has. The `self.kwargs` do not contain the items in the querystring, only the *path* variables.